# Is there a way to setup UiWatchers from appium?

Tags: android, testing, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to test an app using appium. While testing, sometimes there are pop-ups that result in the test failing. To handle these, I was wondering whether appium offers something equivalent to UiWatcher in UiAutomator (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiWatcher.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Appium doesn't support custom UiWatchers:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/PzV2V65HJ_c